# Full pyramid from 5 digit int

Tags: c++

i'm having trouble with my C++ homework..

I need an algorithm that can turn an 5 (x4, x3, x2, x1, x0) digit number, into a pyramid like that:

```
   x2 
 x3x2x1
x4x3x2x1x0
```

Ex. => 12345

```
  3
 234
12345
```

How can I do that? Do I have to take each number individually and display them in order?

Edit*
I did it, and the code looks like (for anyone that might have the same problem):

```
int num; 
  string str; 

  cout << "Type a 5-digit number: ";
  cin >> num;


  stringstream ss;  
  ss << num;  
  ss >> str;  

  char x0 = str[4];
  char x1 = str[3];
  char x2 = str[2];
  char x3 = str[1];
  char x4 = str[0];

  
  cout << "  " << x2 << endl;
  cout << " " << x3 << x2 << x1 << endl;
  cout << x4 << x3 << x2 << x1 << x0;
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I don't understand where to start from.. I've made the program, but with 5 different ints, and after i finished it, i've seen that i need only 1 5 digit int..

Comment: You should take some time to break down your problem into smaller sub-problems. From what I can tell, if you input `12345`, the pyramid extends upwards as the input as the base of the pyramid. Because of this, you need some way of stripping numbers from the left and right-hand side of the number. If you're allowed to convert to a string, that makes it conceptually easier. If you can convert it to a string, definitely go for that.

Comment: Put the integer value in a string, and get sub-strings from that?

Comment: I've been thinking about turning the integer into a string, should that work good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you’d have to process the digits individually.

Generally I’d expect students to try and tackle it in following ways:

1. Convert the number to a string, then index individual characters on that string and display them. There are multiple ways of doing the integer-to-string conversion. The simplest may be to use an `std::ostringstream`, say `(std::ostringstream() << 1234).str()`.
2. Use arithmetic to extract each digit of the string, and convert the digit to a character as it’s passed to a print function. By converting a digit to a character I mean `5 -> '5'`. Incidentally, this conversion is as simple as adding `'0'` to the digit. So, `5+'0' == '5'`. The `'0`' is a number, since in the C family of languages, characters are just small numbers.

There may be many approaches to formatting the pyramid, but since the assignment doesn’t require any flexibility, the simplest way would be the best: add necessary spaces by hand.

Comment: Formatting the pyramid isn't a problem, since I can manually add spaces, the problem I had was with getting each number from the int. I'll try both of the solutions and i'll let you know what happens next. Thanks!

Comment: used the 1st method and works perfectly! Thank you so much!!